# MDAC ADODB in Win 2012 R2

Tags: asp-classic, iis-8, com+, mdac

I've to deploy classic asp application on windows 2K12 R2 environment. This app also uses COM+ component to connect to sql server using adodb sql driver.

As Microsoft has changed MDAC ADODB, creation of object of COM+ is failing. Is there any workaround which can help running older application in newer environment without any code change?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this is a silly question, but have you enabled 32 bit applications in your app pool?

Comment: Q maybe sound silly to you. Enalbing 32b app is not working. App fails to create an object of COM+ obj which establish connection to sql using adodb

Comment: Does win 2012 not have Virtual PCs available?